# Move player on touch Unity C#

Tags: c#, touch, 2d

I created a simple script to move player on Keyboard input, though now I want to move player on touch input, how do I do this ?

Here's my code, so how do I edit this code to make it work ? I have jump working, but dunno how to do it for moving ?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveGround : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float y = 0f;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    //public float x = 0f;
    //public float z = 0f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //move function

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, y);
        }

        if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, -y);
        }
        //move function end
    }

    public void Move()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you figured it out how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to move your character using touch input instead of keyboard input? Your current code moves the character depending on whether the "W" or "S" keys are being pushed.

You could make two UI buttons that correspond to "forward" and "backward" keys.
Add an Event Trigger component to those buttons. Add two event types to the buttons: "Pointer Down" and "Pointer Up."
Add a function to the list of each of those events. 
Put this code onto an object in your scene.

```
bool movingForward;
bool movingBackward;
public float speed = 0f;// set this either here in code or in the editor
public Rigidbody2D rb;

void Start (){

    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();   

    movingForward = false;
    movingBackward = false;

}


// Your forward button will call this function
public void moveForward (){

    movingForward = true;
    movingBackward = false;

}



// Your backwardbutton will call this function
public void moveBackward (){

    movingForward = false;
    movingBackward = true;

}

//


public void stopMoving(){

    movingForward = false;
    movingBackward = false;

}    

void Update () {

    if(movingForward || movingBackward ){// we're moving

            if(movingForward ){// forward

                rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, speed);


        }else if(movingBackward ){// backward

            rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, -speed);

        }

    }else{// we're moving neither forward nor backward

        rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);// so stand still

    }

}
```

Point each function to that object. In the Pointer Down event, choose the "moveForward" function for the button you want to move your character forward, and the "moveBackward" function for the other button.
In the Pointer Up event for both, just choose the "stopMoving" function.

It's really simplistic, but it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @PolakięGames. The best way to do it is creating two UI buttons with `EventTrigger`s attached and assigning the methods `MoveForward` and `MoveBackwards` to `PointerDown` and `StopMoving` to `PointerDown`. Although I would implement it differently:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class MoveExample : MonoBehaviour {
    public float Acceleration = 4f;
    public float Speed = 4f;

    private Vector2 _velocity = Vector2.zero;
    private Rigidbody _rigidbody;

    private void Start() {
        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // movement methods
    public void Move(float velocity) { _velocity.x = velocity * Speed; }
    public void MoveForward() { Move(1f); }
    public void MoveBackwards() { Move(-1f); }
    public void StopMoving() { Move(0f); }

    private void Update() {
        _rigidbody.velocity = Vector2.Lerp(_rigidbody.velocity, _velocity, Time.deltaTime * Acceleration);
    }
}
```

That way your object will move smootly and you can control the speed and acceleration. You have to change `Rigidbody` to `Rigidbody2D` if you intend to use it with 2D Physics.